# How can I count the number of numbers in this line-separated string literal in python?

Tags: python

I want to find the number of numbers in the following string literal 'a'. What am I doing wrong in this code? Is there any way I can find 'count' without manually counting through the string?

I thought of adding commas after each number to make it an array but I am sure there has to be a better way to scrape individual numbers when text is given in such a way.

```
a = """
1004
1003
1003
1002
1001
1000
996
994
992
989
987
984
977
970
963
958
954
951
948
943
939
935
929
917
911
905
903
897
885
878
877
872
857
838
815
796
779
757
725
684
632
578
528
460
258
66
49
42
41
39
39
38
38
38
38
41
53
"""

count = 0
while a:
    if a == '\n':
        count+=1
print count
```

Comment: `a.count('\n')`, maybe minus 1 or 2 (fencepost error).

Comment: Oh, thanks! That makes sense;

Comment: I tried using 
`count = 0
b = a.split('\n')
for i in b:
    count+=1
    
print a.count('\n')
print count`

the first print gives me 58
the second print gives me 59

why are they both conflicting?

Comment: Using `a.split('\n')` with your example gives a list with every number *and* two empty strings, one before and one after. `a.count('\n')` will count the newline before each *and* an extra newline at the very end. Hence the offset by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the number of lines excluding empty lines:

```
print(len([line for line in a.splitlines() if line.strip()]))
```

A solution without a list comprehension:

```
counter = 0
for line in a.splitlines():
    if line.strip():
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use the build-in function `count`

`print a.count('\n') - 1`

I wrote the code,but I don't know whether I can help U.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way.

```
l = a.strip().split('\n')
my_list = list(map(lambda x: l.count(x), set(l)))
print(my_list)
```